# How to install libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 on CentOS 6

Tags: node.js, node-modules, puppeteer, centos6

While launching puppeteer I got a problem

```
    (node:13392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
    /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-674921/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found https://pkgs.org/download/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit) and choose [CentOS 7 version](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/at-spi2-atk-2.26.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html), because there is not CentOS 6 
According to that I typed

```
    yum install at-spi2-atk
```

But got

```
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Setting up Install Process
    Repository remi-php71 is listed more than once in the configuration
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
     * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
     * epel: mirror.wiuwiu.de
     * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
     * remi: mirror.23media.com
     * remi-php54: mirror.23media.com
     * remi-php71: mirror.23media.com
     * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
     * updates: mirror.imt-systems.com
     * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
    No package at-spi2-atk available.
    Error: Nothing to do
```

By the way in Windows 7 puppeteer works with any problems

#### background

CentOS 6, node v10.16.1

#### code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'https://thepage.com.ua/';
puppeteer
    .launch(function() {
        console.log('puppeteer launched')
    })
    .then(function(browser) {
        console.log('browser OK')
        return browser.newPage();
    })
```

Comment: finally I use **request-promise** module

Comment: did you resolve this? I am having the same issue now.

Comment: no. Chromium is not supported in CentOS 6, and I have not updated system yet

Answer (score 1):

`yum install gtk3` provides `libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0`